# Merge branch to the head in CVS problem

Tags: merge, branch, cvs

I understand that CVS is obsolete system in out time but my company use it.
Problem is the next. As usual when developing starts we create branch from head and start work. Some times later we re-base branch with head and merge head with branch. It is ok. But every next typically operations are with problem. **Many-many files are marked as changed, but in fact files hasn't any changes!** . And these files aren't become `white` they `red`. It's a problem, because we need to review all of it to be sure that file modified.
To re-base branch with head we have do (`using WinCVS`):

1.Click `Update..` on some branch;
2.Check `Create missing directories`;
3.Check `Get the clean copy`;
4.Check `Update using last check in time`;
5.Select `Revision to update`;
6.Select `Merge type`.

Any ideas why this can happen?

Thanks.

Comment: May be CVS can merge files and calculate they CRC to compare?

Comment: When you say "many-many files are marked as change" do you mean all files, or most, but not all? Is there anything special about files that were marked as changed (like line endings as @BarsMonster suggested)? Also, can you do `csv status -v <file>` command on one of such files? This might give us some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag the HEAD after each rebase, and next time you rebase, set the root tag to the last tag you made.

Like this:

1. Create BRANCH from HEAD, tag HEAD with BRANCH_ROOT_1
2. Do some work in HEAD
3. Merge HEAD into BRANCH with root branch BRANCH_ROOT_1, tag HEAD with BRANCH_ROOT_2
4. Do some more work in HEAD
5. Merge HEAD into BRANCH with root branch BRANCH_ROOT_2, tag HEAD with BRANCH_ROOT_3
6. ...

GIT and (recently) SVN do this sort of thing automatically, but with CVS you need to do it manually after each merge. It's one of many reasons CVS is to be avoided like the plague.

Comment: Thanks to you very much! It helps for me!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking line endings (Win/Unix).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen problems with all files marked as changed because of time zone problems. For example files checked out on a server using UTC, and copied over the network to a pc using CET. Or a change in daylight savings time caused such problems.

I have always used TortoiseCVS and it's Merge command, so I don't know much about WinCVS.